# DCNN Implementation

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am implementing the DCNN model in this [conference paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9323802).

The attached figure is the model architecture:
The input image size is (256,256,12),and the total number of training images is 90.
The classification categories is 2. (pixelwise classification)
[image: model architecture]

Here is my code:
(I am not sure hoe to achieve the setting of 50% stride in tha paper.)

```
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(100, (8,8), input_shape = (256, 256, 12), activation = 'relu', padding = 'SAME'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(50, (1,1), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(30, (1,1), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(15, (1,1), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation = 'softmax'))

cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="dcnn_model.h5", 
    verbose=1,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

cnn.fit(x_train,y_train,
      batch_size=5,
      epochs=30,
      shuffle=True,
      validation_data=(x_val,y_val),
      callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
```

However, the accuracy and loss seem stuck at the same values.

```
Epoch 1/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 318ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.75150, saving model to dcnn_model.h5
Epoch 2/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 330ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 3/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 334ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 4/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 334ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 5/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 332ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 6/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 331ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 7/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 334ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 8/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 334ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.75150
Epoch 9/10
30/30 [==============================] - 10s 333ms/step - loss: 3.5711 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 3.7894 - val_accuracy: 0.7515
```

How can I revise the code?

Comment: You cannot use softmax with one output neuron, think about why, that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture you have is not exactly like the paper but the main issue is that you have a `Conv2D` with a `softmax` activation function instead of a `sigmoid`. If you have a binary classification problem you should use the `sigmoid` activation function and `1` unit for the `Dense` layer, instead of `softmax`. You **can't use softmax and 1 dense node** because when you use a `softmax` then the sum of the probabilities has to be 1 and if you only have 1 node then the probability will always be 1 which does not make sense.

Comment: The setting of the number of units to 2 will report an error `ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((5, 256, 256, 2) vs (5, 256, 256))`.  So I set the number of units to 1 and set the threshold on the value in the test phase (i.e., threshold=0.5).

Comment: I change the output layer using `Dense`, but the accuracy and loss are still stuck at the same values.

Comment: Is it a binary classification problem? What are the labels? Check the edit please

Comment: I misread your question and didn't see it was a pixelwise classification. I made an edit to the answer to take this into account